# Preposition for a time period

Tags: prepositions

When I'm trying to say "The class will be held (on, in, during . . . ) 15-20 July, 2014" which preposition is more appropriate ?

Comment: You can just say, "The class will be held July 15-20, 2013"

Comment: Kristina's suggestion is good. Or you could spend a few more words and phrases and make it clear that the first class meets on the 15th and the last one meets on the 20th. Don't depend on a preposition to do exposition.

Answer (score 3):

I would use *from*, and read the sentence thus: "The class will be held from the fifteenth to the twentieth of July, 2014."

Searching Google Books for various vague strings like ["held from 15"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22held%20from%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#safe=off&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22held%20from%2015%22&oq=%22held%20from%2015%22&gs_l=serp.3...74573.75956.1.76300.3.3.0.0.0.0.211.331.2j0j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.qPnttQmxtOU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48340889,d.dmQ&fp=3cd09cfb944888&biw=1920&bih=956), ["held from July"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22held%20from%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#safe=off&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22held%20from%20July%22&oq=%22held%20from%20July%22&gs_l=serp.3...169263.171369.2.171483.13.9.4.0.0.0.171.774.7j2.9.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.iYTeh7uTcAQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48340889,d.dmQ&fp=3cd09cfb944888&biw=1920&bih=956), etc. returns sentences similar to yours from official-looking books and journals, so I would feel comfortable using *from*.

Comment: And to avoid any (?) possibility of confusion (See John Lawler's comments), if it's a six day conference, one could add 'inclusive' after 'July'.

Comment: Do not use *from* if you actually leave the dash in there. (Which should be an actual en dash and not a hyphen.) If you use *from*, you must drop the dash and actually substitute the *to* for it in writing, not just in your head.